# Deleted Page in Drupal Still Showing Up

Tags: drupal

I deleted a page in Drupal and I confirmed it by logging to the page. It shows a page not found on my browser. However, some viewers are still able to see the page.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Ack, sorry. I found the way! I cleared Drupal's cache!